# An error was thrown in afterAll ReferenceError: Cannot access 'SubscriptionEditIconComponent' before initialization

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, ag-grid

i create an **ag-grid** and i am running the **unit test** of my module its frequently showing this error. i am not able to identify why this error is coming.

***An error was thrown in afterAll

ReferenceError: Cannot access 'SubscriptionEditIconComponent' before initialization***

SubscriptionDeleteIconComponent is an child component of ag-grid which contain a delete icon

## Spec file

```
    import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
    import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform- 
    browser/animations';
    import { ComponentsModule } from 
     'src/app/common/components/components.module';
    import { dialogMock, S

ubscriptionDataMock, SubscriptionServiceMock } from 
    '../../mocks/subscription.mock';
    import { SubscriptionService } from '../../services/subscription.service';

    import { SubscriptionEditIconComponent } from './subscription-edit- 
    icon.component';

    fdescribe('SubscriptionEditIconComponent', () => {
      let component: SubscriptionEditIconComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<SubscriptionEditIconComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SubscriptionEditIconComponent ],
      imports: [
        ComponentsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: SubscriptionService, useClass: SubscriptionServiceMock },
        { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: dialogMock },
        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} },
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
       fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SubscriptionEditIconComponent);
       component = fixture.componentInstance;
       fixture.detectChanges();
    });

      it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });
    });
```

## ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { PopupComponent } from 's

rc/app/common/components/popup/popup.component';
import { SubscriptionService } from '../../services/subscription.service';
import { SubscriptionPopupComponent } from '../subscription- 
popup/subscription-popup.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'aiq-subscription-edit-icon',
  templateUrl: './subscription-edit-icon.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./subscription-edit-icon.component.scss']
})
export class SubscriptionEditIconComponent  implements 
ICellRendererAngularComp {

  params = {
    reportId: '',
    subscriptionName: ''
  };
  @ViewChild("reviewSubscriptionPopup", { static: false }) 
reviewSubscriptionPopup: PopupComponent;

  constructor(public service: SubscriptionService) { }

  agInit(params: any): void {
   
  }

  refresh(): boolean {
    return false;
  }   
}
```

if directly run only this component it ll not run. Its ag-grid internal component. i.e we are showing ag-grid and inside that one edit icon is there if we click on that it ll allow as to edit the data of that row.

Comment: We need more code. Could you pls. add the `spec` code where you're trying to run the unit test?

Comment: not just `spec` code but also `component` code to understand it better. Else this will be closed shortly